# No JDK 13 da Oracle tem Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, java-13

Vi que agora a Oracle tem um JDK13, tenho a dúvida se ele vem com um Javafx, como no JDK8 vinha com o Javafx8, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com [esse link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html) do site da Oracle, desde o lançamento do JDK 11 em 2018 que o JavaFX foi movido para o OpenJDK como projeto OpenJFX, e tem seu próprio [site oficial](https://openjfx.io/index.html). [Um post no blog da Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates) foi criado pra explicar com mais detalhes essa transição.